# bashrc syntax error after adding ANDROID_HOME

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, android, bashrc

I encountered the following error:

```
bash: /home/william/.bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/william/.bashrc: line 1: `i# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.'
```

This is what I added to my .bashrc file:

[image: android file path]

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/william/Android/Sdk/
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

[image: the error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first character of the first line of your `.bashrc` is an `i`. It shouldn't be there. Remove it.

Comment: me <3 you long time :D